# retrieve all files unders subfolders in sharepoint document library using REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, folder

I have a folder in a document library and that contains subfolders and each subfolder contains files.

I want to retrieve all the files in these subfolders using REST. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an endpoint like this `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File&$filter=ContentType ne 'Folder'`

It will list all files under the library.

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint solved my problem:

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Library Name/Folder Name/')?$expand=Folders,Folders/Files
```

For more information, check [this article](https://sympmarc.com/2016/04/23/get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-at-a-serverrelativeurl-in-one-rest-call/).