# Can you search a title of a document from a higher level folder which would search all folders held within it?

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have a number of sub folders within a folder and I would like to search ALL folders for a document title.

Title:"document name" doesn't work all the time, and in some cases only brings back sub folders with the same name not documents held within them.

Is it possible or am I asking too much?

Comment: Is the content search enabled? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-subfolders-and-search/09a56aba-1b2e-45da-b866-a6565b4673ea Are you using REST API? `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File&$filter=ContentType ne 'Folder'` See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293845/retrieve-all-files-unders-subfolders-in-sharepoint-document-library-using-rest